# Laravel & React | How to implement one view per one component?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to integrate Laravel with React that has multiple hierarchical components. However, I don't want these components to be bundled in one single view. How I view it, the current capability of Laravel is to route a single view to one single request. My react component hierarchy is as follows:

```
Main React App
├─ Subcomponent A
└─ Subcomponent B
```

However, I only want to fetch each of the subcomponents at certain events in the Main React App. Specifically, I want to get the subcomponents from the server only if the subcomponent will be included in the DOM tree. The fetching must be done with Laravel views.

Is it possible to implement this with Laravel and React?

Comment: It sounds like you are after dynamic imports? Are you saying that you only want the source code for Subcomponent B to load if you are using Subcomponent B on the page?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I'm implementing is closer to server-side rendering. For example, a button from the App component will fetch then render Subcomponent A

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will need to manually create Laravel web routes that will allow you to fetch the components. For instance, if `Component A` requires `Component B` from server, a web route (or a shared web route) must be made. Here's a demo:

**/routes/web.php**

```
// the route which returns your react app engine
Route::get('home-page', function(){
    return view('home_page');
});


// the route used to fetch components dynamically
Route::get('react-components/{component_name}', function($component_name){

    // you can either wrap your components in blade files
    return view('react_components.'.$component_name);

    // or manually read them from disk and return them as plain-text responses
    return response(
        // you can use Storage facade: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem
        \Storage::disk('react_comps')->get($component_name)

        // or primitive method
        file_get_contents(base_path().'/views/assets/react_comps/'.$component_name)
    );
});
```

Then, when you want to fetch the component, use the route:

```
axios.get('/react-components/posts.js')
.then(res=>{
    // do stuff with res.data
})
```